# Android studio error in java main activity?

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I am dealing with a problem with compile errors in my java code which I cannot understand how to correct.

First error:

> main cannot be resolved or is not a field ....

Second error:

> The method OnKeyListener(new MainActivity.OnKeyListener(){}) is undefined for the type EditText

```
package com.uichat;    
import android.app.Activity;    
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.DataSetObserver;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AbsListView;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ListView;
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;

public class MainActivity extends Activity{
    private ChatArrayAdapter adp;
    private ListView list;
    private EditText ChatText;
    private Button send;
    Intent In;

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        Intent I = getIntent();
        send = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn);
        list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
        adp = new ChatArrayAdapter(getApplicationContext(), R.layout.chat);
        ChatText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.chat);
        ChatText.setKeyListener(new OnKeyListener() {
            public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
                if ((event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN) && (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER)) {
                    return sendChatMessage(false);
                }
                return false;
            }
        });

        send.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                sendChatMessage(false);
            }
        });
        list.setTranscriptMode(AbsListView.TRANSCRIPT_MODE_ALWAYS_SCROLL);
        list.setAdapter(adp);

        adp.registerDataSetObserver(new DataSetObserver() {
            @Override
            public void onChanged() {
                super.onChanged();
                list.setSelection(adp.getCount() - 1);
            }
        });
    }

    private boolean sendChatMessage(boolean side) {
        adp.add(new ChatMessage(side, ChatText.getText().toString()));
        ChatText.setText("");
        side = !side;
        return true;
    }

    public ListView getList() {
        return list;
    }

    public void setList(ListView list) {
        this.list = list;
    }

    class EditView {
        private String text;

        public void setOnKeyListener(OnKeyListener onKeyListener) {
        }

        public boolean getText() {
            return true;
        }

        public void setText(String text) {
            this.text = text;
        }
    }

    class OnKeyListener {
    }
}
```

Comment: It will be helpful if you include the errors/stack trace.

Comment: What error are you getting?  It's hard to help when we don't even know what's wrong.

Comment: second error .The method OnKeyListener(new MainActivity.OnKeyListener(){}) is undefined for the type EditText

Comment: Second error import the `OnKeyListener`

Comment: first error: main cannot be resolved or is not a field ....   
 
second error .The method OnKeyListener(new MainActivity.OnKeyListener(){}) is undefined for the type EditText

Comment: Check your `main` xml

Comment: import android.view.View.OnKeyListener; not working

Comment: main xml is fine brother

Answer (score 1):

First Error:

> main cannot be resolved or is not a field ....

```
setContentView(R.layout.main);
```

Attempts to reference a non-existent field of R.layout called "main"

It is missing either because you do not have a valid "main.xml" in your res/layout tree, or because you need to clean and rebuild your project to update changes there.  (Accidentally importing Android's own R class could do it too, but you haven't done that in your provided code).

Second error:

> The method OnKeyListener(new MainActivity.OnKeyListener(){}) is undefined for the type EditText

The method you should be calling for an EditText is `setOnKeyListener()`

the argument you pass will need to be a class which implements `View.onKeyListener`

Therefore your internal

```
class OnKeyListener {
}
```

Needs to have the required method

```
class OnKeyListener {
     public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
       //insert code here
       return true;
     }
}
```

see http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnKeyListener.html

Comment: every thing is working now but thr is one new error ... ChatText.OnKeyListener(new OnKeyListener() {.... the is on ChatText

Comment: As I have pointed out here ChatText.OnKeyListener() is not valid.  You need to call the setOnKeyListener() method.

Comment: i have tried it to but the error remain the same i also tried to change in r.java but nothing

Comment: If you are still getting the error about ChatText.OnKeyListener then you have not applied the suggestion here, which was to **replace the usage of that non-existent method with the proper one, setOnKeyListener()**.

Comment: done it worked but if you don't mind and allow me to ask a little reasoning on this why this was  giving an error. secondly would that be okay if i ask your email id

Comment: It didn't work because you called something which does not exist, rather than the method which does.